# Look for multiple classes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script to hide/show a table row. I'd like it to look for an additional class, but I can seem to get it to work.  Here is the original:

```
    jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".toggle").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find(".hide1").slideToggle("none");
    });
});
```

I tried adding an 'or' operator to specify another class, but that doesn't work:

```
    jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".toggle").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find(".hide1" || ".hide2").slideToggle("none");
    });
});
```

Can someone point out my error - Javascript is not my strong suit.

Comment: Please post the HTML you're working with.

Comment: I don't really think it is necessarily in this case.  The JS seemed to be clear enough given the quantity of correct answers.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Possibly not *necessary*, but it might have improved the answers at least a little to see what you're working with. But if the posted answers work, and solve your problem, then perhaps not in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a comma. This is the *[multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)*.

```
.find(".hide1,.hide2")
```

---

Doing...

```
.find(".hide1" || ".hide2")
```

...is valid code, but it will be interpreted as...

```
.find(".hide1")
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
find(".hide1,.hide2")
```

See: [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

just give it comma separated

```
.find(".hide1,.hide2").
```

Answer (score 2):

To find either class-name, just use a comma-separated list:

```
.find('.hide1, .hide2')
```

This assumes, of course, that the rest of your jQuery works.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick!

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".toggle").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find('.hide1, .hide2').slideToggle("none");
    });
});
```